# loading devices greyed out in android studio how to solve this issue?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Recently I installed flutter plugin in android studio and I installed the sdk from flutter website. I placed in c and I edited in environment. In android studio, loading devices greyed out IDK how to solve that one. [image]

Comment: Does Invalidate cache and restart work?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and restart

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Android Studio version 2021.2.1 where the device was recognized but greyed out in the device selection box.

My solution was to exit Android Studio then delete the entire "project name"/.idea directory, then restart Android Studio.